# How can I prefix a value in a python dictionary used for an Ansible dynamic inventory?

Tags: python, dictionary, ansible, prefix

I'm working on a custom Ansible dynamic inventory python script. I have created groups from k=v pairs, but for certain groups, I want the key prefixed to the values, otherwise the group names are meaningless (1,2,3, etc.)

I've tried sticking the key name in various places, but without a proper understanding of what I'm doing. In the example below, I am trying to get the "bucket" group to have every value look something like bucket_3 (which would then be the Ansible group name).

```py
result = {
  'all': {
    'hosts': [],
    'vars': {},
   },
  '_meta': {
    'hostvars': {}
   }
}
server = ''
for raw_line in output.split('\n'):
    line = raw_line.strip()
    if len(line) > 0 and not line.startswith(comment_char):
        if line.endswith(server_char):
            server = line[:-1]
            result['all']['hosts'].append(server)
            result['_meta']['hostvars'][server] = {}
        else:
            raw_key, raw_value = line.split('=', 1)
            key = raw_key.strip()
            value = raw_value.strip()
            result['_meta']['hostvars'][server][key] = value
            if key == 'ansible_groups':
                for group in value.split(","):
                    if group not in result.keys():
                        result[group] = {'hosts': [], 'vars': {}}
                    result[group]['hosts'].append(server)
            if key == 'bucket':
                for group in value:
                    if group not in result.keys():
                        result[group] = 'bucket_' + {'hosts': [], 'vars': {}}
                    result[group]['hosts'].append(server)
```

I expect to get groups such as bucket_1, bucket_2, etc. (The source has 'bucket = 1', 'bucket = 2', etc.).

Getting error "'bucket_' + {'hosts': [], 'vars': {}} TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and
'dict' objects"

granted, this is just my latest attempt, so errors have been varied as I try to find the correct way to modify the group name.

Answer (score 0):

nevermind...just not thinking.

```py
if key == 'bucket': 
    for group in value: 
        group = 'bucket_' + group 
        if group not in result.keys():
```

still a bit slower than I would like, but it is functional